# SpringBootTest - scan packages for Configuration files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am writing an integration test that requires (essentially) the whole App Context to run. I have about 20 Context Configuration classes located in packages `com.A` and `com.B`. My integration test is located in package `com.X`. My integration test needs to spin up all Context Configurations in `com.A` and `com.B`.

Not having a lot of experience with Spring Boot, I was hoping it would let me simply annotate the test class like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.A", "com.B" })
public class AbcIntegrationTest(){
```

This guess did not work. The test threw an IllegalArgumentException, with the following error:

```
Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

Based on the error message, I tried to replace my `@ComponentScan` with a `@ContextConfiguration`. Unfortunately, ContextConfiguration requires a list of Configuration classes, but I need something that can scan the packages containing the Configuration classes. (I have 20-odd classes, and they'll probably be refactored soon. Listing these 20 classes out in ContextConfiguration does not fit my usecase.)

So now I don't know what to do. I started reading the documentation but I haven't found anything that does what I need it to do. Is there any way that my SpringBootTest can load all of the Context Configuration classes in a given package?

Comment: can you move your integration test to package `com` (parent package), and then just annotate it with SpringBootTest and RunWith(SpringRunner.class)?

Comment: Create a context class in your test scope that lists out all 20 of those classes, and then use *that* in your test class as your context.

Comment: If this is a Spring Boot application, then you have a launcher class somewhere. Point `@SpringBootTest` at it to bootstrap.

Comment: Possible test build error, all yours 20 config classes are not in classpath of test execution. Just add one config class to be sure it is present otherwise you will got classnotfoundexception

Comment: @chrylis Right now, my integration tests pull in my core module and my Spring Boot application also pulls in my core module, but my integration tests do not pull in my Spring Boot application. My Spring Boot application does not contain my Configuration classes, those are in my core module. Maybe I should restructure my project and take my Configuration classes out of core?